# Creating my own custom link to a WooCommerce login page

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

How can I link my register / login link to the WooCommerce login / register page? I have done a similar thing with the cart page like this

```
<li class="head_bot_line"><a href="<?php echo WC()->cart->get_cart_url(); ?>">View Basket</a></li>
```

Is this the correct way to do it? If so how do I link this link to the login / register page?

```
<li class="head_bot_line"><a href="">Login / Register</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to echo the *My Account* page URL. And WooCOmmerce will decide and will redirect the user.

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id') ); ?>" title="<?php _e('My Account','woothemes'); ?>"><?php _e('My Account','woothemes'); ?></a>
 <?php } 
 else { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id') ); ?>" title="<?php _e('Login / Register','woothemes'); ?>"><?php _e('Login / Register','woothemes'); ?></a>
 <?php } ?>
```

Official doc: [Display My Account link in a template file](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/display-my-account-link-in-a-template-file/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I managed to solve it already but the code you found is much better. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it myself using this code

```
<li class="head_bot_line"><a href="<?php echo wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' )?>">Login / Register</a></li>
```